# Getting POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_thumbnail_batch 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: dropbox-api

I am trying to fetch data using dbx.getThumbnailsBatch:

```
 const response = await fetch(`https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_thumbnail_batch`, {
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer <REDACTED>",
        "data": `{\"entries\":[{\"path\":\"${JSON.stringify(folders)}\"}]}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"

      },
    });

    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json)
```

And I'm getting these errors:

```
POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_thumbnail_batch 400 (Bad Request)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at App.js:73:1)
    at nextImgs (App.js:73:1)
```

Can anyone tell why is this happening?

Comment: List the code for App.js on line 73.

Comment: It's  const json = await response.json();

Comment: You're attempting to parse the response as JSON, but it may not necessarily be JSON. Try reading the raw response without parsing it as JSON.